# Segmentation fault at std::thread

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, stdthread

```
typedef struct _ppm_struct* ppm_struct;
typedef unsigned char ppm_subpixel;

typedef ppm_subpixel (*ppm_pixel_func)(ppm_subpixel);
struct ppm_pixel {
   ppm_subpixel red;
   ppm_subpixel green;
   ppm_subpixel blue;
};

struct _ppm_struct {
   unsigned int width;
   unsigned int height;
   unsigned int max_color;
   ppm_pixel *firstpixel;
};
```

So I have this function call:

```
void pppm_color_pixel(ppm_struct p, ppm_struct out, ppm_pixel_func func, int threads) {
//ppm_pixel_func func2 = &inverse_pixel;
unsigned int w = p->width;
unsigned int h = p->height;
ppm_pixel *iterator = p->firstpixel;
std::thread th[threads];

long long total_pixels = w*h;
unsigned int count_for_thread = total_pixels/threads;

for(int j = 0; j<threads; ++j) {

   th[j] = std::thread(pppm_color_chunk_pixel,func, *iterator,count_for_thread);
   iterator = &iterator[count_for_thread];
}

for(int j = 0; j<threads; ++j) {
    th[j].join();
}
```

The next two function: funct is inverse subpixel

```
ppm_subpixel inverse_subpixel(ppm_subpixel subpixel) {
    subpixel = 255- subpixel;
    return subpixel;
}

void pppm_color_chunk_pixel(ppm_pixel_func func, ppm_pixel start_pixel, unsigned int count) {
    ppm_pixel *iterator = &start_pixel;
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i< count; ++i) {
        iterator[i].red = func(iterator[i].red);
        iterator[i].green = func(iterator[i].green);
        iterator[i].blue = func(iterator[i].blue);
    }
}
```

The main:

```
pppm_color_pixel(p,out, &inverse_subpixel,pppm_get_max_cores());
```

The problem is that when I run this it shows me a segmentation fault. This happen on this line:

```
iterator[i].green = func(iterator[i].green);
```

What I really don't understand is that `i = 2` or more when this happens. It doesn't crash from the first time. Even if I try to call only a single thread the result is the same.

Comment: Looping over `threads` and then using `th[0]` looks wrong. You might wanted to use `th[j]` instead.

Comment: There was th[j].  It remains th[o] from test with only one thread. So the problem is still present

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pppm_color_chunk_pixel` accepts a copy of `ppm_pixel`. Since it is copied by value, passing `*iterator` to it will cause only one element to be copied. Iterating over anything after `&start_pixel` will fail.
Since `std::thread` doesn't pass objects by reference, you also need a reference-wrapper for this.

```
void pppm_color_chunk_pixel(ppm_pixel_func func, ppm_pixel& start_pixel, unsigned int count) {
ppm_pixel* iterator = &start_pixel;
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    iterator[i].red   = func(iterator[i].red);
    iterator[i].green = func(iterator[i].green);
    iterator[i].blue  = func(iterator[i].blue);
}
```

Calling it:

```
for (int j = 0; j < threads; ++j) {
   th[j] = std::thread(pppm_color_chunk_pixel, func, std::ref(*iterator), count_for_thread);
   iterator = &iterator[count_for_thread];
}
```

I have not tested it, but I guess this is your problem.

Comment: @MSD561 Glad I could help. In general: Have a look at passing arguments by value / by reference (how it works and when you need what). For example: Your parameter `out` sounds like you want to modify it in the function. But this modification will have no effect on the calling code because you are working on a copy of `out`. Also have a look at `const`, it will help you once you starting using reference arguments more often.

Comment: ppm_struct is  a pointer to a structure  -> typedef struct _ppm_struct* ppm_struct; i think that out is not a copy, but a pointer. Am I wrong?

Comment: Ah, yes I see. Ok then it will work, however I don't think it is very helpful to write code like this, you're only making it hard to read and understand. At least call the typedef something like ppm_struct_ptr.